# Is it possible to add custom costs for GameObjects with specific tags in NavMeshPlus library for Unity 2D?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am trying to implement pathfinding into my 2D unity game and I found NavMeshPlus library that helps to create a NavMesh in 2D projects and it works perfectly out of the box, but during the implementation of this library I started to wonder is it somehow possible to make the modification to the costs? To add some custom costs for GameObjects with specific tags. For example: NPC is moving from point A to point B, but if there is a GameObject with "Speed" tag, it tries to build his way through the object with the "Speed" tag.

I didn't find any documentation on that so tried to build my own custom script but didn't really managed to do it.

Are there any solutions for that, or better to use any other library? If so, what are the best library to implement such scenario? Thanks.

Comment: It is possible. Figured out that NavMeshPlus has this function out of the box, you just have to add a new layer and set a custom cost in inspector.